# NWConnection using TLS fails in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, wss, network.framework

I was able to connect to a public wss using tls like this:

```
let port = 443
let url = URL(string: "wss://echo.websocket.org")!
connection = NWConnection(host: NWEndpoint.Host.name(url.host!, nil), port: NWEndpoint.Port(rawValue: UInt16(port))!, using: .tls)
```

Now I'm trying to connect to a wss websocket in a private network and I'm getting some errors. This is my code:

```
let port = 8443
let url = URL(string: "wss://ip_address:8443/gs-guide-websocket/websocket")!
connection = NWConnection(host: NWEndpoint.Host.name(url.host!, nil), port: NWEndpoint.Port(rawValue: UInt16(port))!, using: .tls)
```

And these are the errors:

> [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_alert_callback_handler(3747) [C1.1:1][0x7fe945708390] Alert level: fatal, description: certificate unknown
>   
> [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_error_print(3699) boringssl ctx 0x600001ec9500: 140639868076392:error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl_Sim/boringssl-109.202.1/ssl/handshake.cc:372:
> [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_get_error_code(3519) [C1.1:1][0x7fe945708390] SSL_AD_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN
>   
> Client failed with error: -9808: Optional(bad certificate format)

Do I need to add special options to connect here?

Also, I saw that the wss works because I'm able to connect with SocketRocket, but I want to connect with NWConnection

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to install the certificate that I had on the server and then enable full trust to that certificate in Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings

Comment: Can you describe how you did that?